# Как проверить, является ли возрастающей последовательность чисел?

Tags: php

Я новичок в PHP, и у меня возник следующий вопрос:
имеется массив, элементы которого являются целыми числами:

```
$numbers = [4, 5, 6, 7];
```

Необходимо написать функцию, которая проверяет, является ли переданная последовательность целых чисел возрастающей непрерывно (не имеющей пропусков чисел). Как реализовать данную функцию?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function check(array $numbers){
    if(empty($array)) return false;
    $first = reset($numbers);
    if(!is_int($first)) return false;
    foreach($numbers as $current) {
        if( $current !== $first) return false;
        $first++;
    }
    return true;
}
```

**UPD** Добавил проверку на то, что в массиве числа и независимость от ключей.

**UPD** Учел замечание @Akina

**UPD** Рекурсия (раз пошла такая пьянка)

```
function check(array $numbers, $prev = null){
    if(empty($numbers)) return true;
    $current = array_shift($numbers);
    if($prev == null || $current === $prev + 1) return check($numbers, $current);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: А последний " return true;" не перебьет предыдущий "return false;"?

Comment: @Keeplod с какого перепугу?

Comment: @Keeplod если сработает первый return - он остановит выполнение функции

Comment: А не проще инкрементить сразу $first и не заводить дополнительную $i?

Comment: @Akina да. Это артефакт от первой реализации

Comment: `++` то можно и в условие добавить, а не отдельной строкой

Comment: @teran это уже вкусовщина. Лично я не люблю адские однострочники внутри if'ов :)

Answer (score 2):

Функция ниже проверит входной массив на возрастание и отсутствие пропусков чисел.

```
function checkNumbers($ar) {
    for($i = $ar[0]; $i>$ar[count($ar)-2]; $i++) {
        if($ar[$i]>$ar[$i+1] || $ar[$i] + 1 != $ar[$i+1])
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: пост про то, как писать запутанный код.

Answer (score 1):

Немного измененный вариант от rjhdby

```
function isContinuousSequence($array)
{
    if(empty($array)) return false;
    $first = reset($array);
    foreach ($array as $i => $num) {
        if( $num !== $i + $first) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Выдаст ошибку, если первый элемент не число или если ключи не числовые

Comment: Это так, но по условиям задачи в массиве исключительно числа, и от этого никуда не деться, поэтому проверку опустил. А в целом согласен с вами

Answer (score 1):

Для полноты ответов, способ более "функциональный":

```php
function check_array($numbers) {
    return !array_filter(array_map(
        function($b,$a){ return $b-$a-1; },   //  --> [0,0,0]
        array_slice($numbers,1),              //  ^   [5,6,7]
        array_slice($numbers,0,-1))           //   ^  [4,5,6]
    );
}
```

В этом способе копия массива сдвигается на один элемент вбок, вычитается с оригиналом и затем итоговый массив проверяется на пустоту. Если есть хоть один непоследовательный элемент, итоговый массив не будет пуст, и функция вернёт false.